# Put a prefix to page title when editing an answer/question

Tags: feature-request, design, editor

When using SO, I have several tabs open simultaneously. One tab, for instance, shows me the new or recently active questions. When a new question arrives, the title is prefixed with the number of new questions, like (2) for two questions. In this manner it is very easy to spot changes.

In another situation, 
when editing a question, I frequently refer to related pages, such that I have many tabs open. It is often difficult to find the tab where I am editing.

Suggestion: Prefix the title of a page that is currently edited with, say, *.

Comment: Note that * is already used for chat tabs when you have been pinged.